# UV map not showing up for new additions

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, edit-mode

Alright So I'm working on something that already had a UV map and I'm adding onto it. I opened up the UV editor to see what I was working with and low and behold the UV map for the new additions are not there I worked on seams for the new addition but I really do not want to redo the seams for the whole object. What do I need to do to be able to open the additional object AND the old object in the UV editor should I make them separate objects or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

The safest is to create a new UV Map via the Data tab in the Properties window within the UV Maps section, and then prepare and unwrap your additional geometry.

[image]